# Обработать действие при нажатии кнопки уведомления без запуска Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, уведомления

```js
// создание уведомления в Service
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ARG_FRAGMENT, ARG_FRAGMENT_PURPOSE);
intent.putExtra(ARG_ID, task.getForeignId());
intent.putExtra(ARG_TASK_ID, task.getId());
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent intentTaskDone = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intentTaskDone.putExtra(ARG_ACTION, ARG_ACTION_TASK_DONE);
intentTaskDone.putExtra(ARG_TASK_ID, task.getId());
PendingIntent contentIntentTaskDone = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentTaskDone, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_TASK_ID);
builder.setContentTitle(Objects.requireNonNull(purpose).getTitle());
builder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.completion_time_of_this_task_ended));
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_task);
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(task.getDescription()));
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_done, "Выполнено", contentIntentTaskDone);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

// проверка Bundles в MainActivity
// проверка действий
int actionID = bundle.getInt(ARG_ACTION, ARG_ACTION_DEFAULT); // получаем айди действия
if (actionID != ARG_ACTION_DEFAULT) { // если айди действия не пустой
  if (actionID == ARG_ACTION_TASK_FINISH) {
    int taskId = bundle.getInt(ARG_TASK_ID, ARG_TASK_ID_EMPTY); // получаем айди задачи
    if (taskId != ARG_TASK_ID_EMPTY) // если айди цели не пустой
      database.setTaskFinishByID(taskId, true); // обновляем значение в бд
  }
}
```

Comment: Запустите BroadcastReceiver или WorkManager

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в targetSdk = 31 такие трамплины запрещены. Приложение не будет падать, но ничего не произойдет. Из notification теперь можно открывать только activity. Гипотетически для своих нужд можно использовать пустую activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// создал NotificationActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  moveTaskToBack(true); // !!! важно помещаем активити в конец стека действий
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  initDatabase(); // инициализируем базу данных
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  // проверка действий
  int actionId = bundle.getInt(ARG_ACTION, ARG_ACTION_DEFAULT); // получаем айди действия
  if (actionId != ARG_ACTION_DEFAULT) { // если айди действия не пустой
    if (actionId == ARG_ACTION_TASK_FINISH) { // если действие - завершение задачи
      int taskId = bundle.getInt(ARG_TASK_ID, ARG_TASK_ID_EMPTY); // получаем айди задачи
      if (taskId != ARG_TASK_ID_EMPTY) { // если айди задачи не пустой
        database.setTaskFinishByID(taskId, true); // обновляем значение в бд
        notificationManager.cancel(taskId); // отменяем уведомление по айди
      }
    }
  }
  finish();
}

Добавил атрибуты в AndroidManifest.xml для выполнения на заднем плане
<activity
    android:name=".NotificationActivity"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```